# Rails mock call FROM external web service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec-rails

I've seen a lot of posts of how to mock external service requests during tests to improve test suite's speed and make them functional even without connection using gems like Webmock or VCR.

Now I have a route that gets called FROM an external service. i.e the external service POSTs to my app. How could I mock that?

Comment: You can use the faraday gem of else others to make the call.

Comment: Is there any way to record one real call? It is called with really a LOT of very long parameters.

Comment: May be available but I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I have a route that gets called FROM an external service. i.e the
>   external service POSTs to my app.

This means your application provides a public API through one of your controller. To test the public API, you simply test the corresponding action in your controller as you always do when testing controllers.

Here's [a reference](http://matthewlehner.net/rails-api-testing-guidelines/).

Comment: So I should mock all parameters that the external service will send, right?

Comment: You can pass actual values. For example, your API requires 5 parameters, when testing you can post 5 values for those parameters. I don't see why mocking should be done here.

Comment: Yes, well, that's what I intended when I said 'mock'. That I have to send parameters manually looking at what comes from external service once.